# Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from productsApp

Tags: html, angularjs, json, xml

this is link of my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/8muxhJmvFiIqRJgzuT0O?p=preview

I am getting error 
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from productsApp

and I can't view json file in console

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="productsApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
 <script  type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script> 
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
</head>

  <body >
<div ng-controller="products">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <div ng-repeat="platform in product ">
        {{platform._type}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

product_js.js    -  js file for x2js

```
var productApp = angular.module("productsApp",[]);
productApp.factory('productFactory',function($http){
    var factory = [];
    factory.getProducts = function(){
        return $http.get("operations_mapping.xml");
    }
    return factory;
});
productApp.controller('products',function($scope,productFactory){
    $scope.products = [];
    loadProducts();
    function loadProducts(){
        productFactory.getProducts().success(function(data){
            mappingss = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
            console.log(mappingss.mappings.platform);
            $scope.products =mappingss.mappings.platform;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why `var factory = [];` this is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have included multiple version of angular.js script on your page, retain the latest one(mentioned below) and remove the rest of the references.

`<script data-require="angularjs@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">`

[Here is the Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQJ2Q645sgSm8qe2nPLe?p=preview)

Comment: Ty for answer! Why's like that though?

Comment: @KennyNguyen: there were multiple version's of angular.js on the page & it was conflicting, refer my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

product_js.js is not included in your html. Add `<script  type='text/javascript' src="product_js.js"></script>`